# window.onbeforeunload triggered in parent page when defined in child page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to trigger the window.onbeforeunload method while the user tries to refresh the browser and show a messsage to save his current work before leaving. 
I am doing an angularjs application. 
The below is my landing page url

```
http:localhost:9000/#/parentPage/
```

After button click user is navigated to

```
http:localhost:9000/#/parentPage/childPage1/:id
```

In childPage1Ctrl i defined the method for load

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return "This is a message to remind you to save your experiment before leaving the page";
};
```

But when I launch the application the onbeforeunload method is being called.

1. How do i prevent this and bind the method to only that particular page?
2. How can i reload a particular childpage and access the id from the url?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `child contorller js` destroy or Unregister the onbeforeunload event when the scope is out of this controller.

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    delete window.onbeforeunload;
});
```